# Path to image in CDN tax receipt extension

Tags: extension, cdn-tax-receipts

The images I use in my CDN tax receipts are stored as a full path but the container code that comes after /srv/bindings/ changes from time to time which makes it that the files are not found.

How can I store these images as relative paths?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but noting that recent versions of the cdntax receipts extension store them as relative paths (since 1.6.0). Upgrading will automatically update the stored path.